# R: ggplot2 not accepting "weeks" date format

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have data in R that is in the form of : week -year (e.g. 21-03, the 21st week of 2003). In my real data, these dates appear in character format.

I am trying to plot this data in R, but the date formatting is not working properly. I tried to recreate the data as close as I can, and then run the plots:

```
library(dplyr) 
 library(ggplot2) 
 library(reshape2)  
library(scales)
library(lubridate)       

  Table_1 <- data.frame(  "Col_A" = c("21-03", "21-03", "21-03", "21-04", "21-04", "21-04", "21-05", "21-05", "21-05"), 
 "Col_B" = c("AAA", "AAB", "AAC", "AAA", "ABB", "AAC", "AAA", "AAB", "AAC"), 
 "Col_C" = c(111, 122.5, 9, 727, 66.4, 3, 992, 88, 12)      )

Table_1$col_A_Date <- as.Date(Table_1$col_A, format = "%W-%y")
 Table_1$Col_B = as.factor(Table_1$Col_B) 
 Table_1$Col_C = as.numeric(Table_1$Col_C) 

melt = melt(Table_1, id = c("Col_A"))  

p = ggplot(melt, aes(x = Col_A, y=value, group = 1)) + geom_line(aes(color=variable)) +
 facet_grid(variable ~., scales = "free_y") + scale_x_date(date_labels = "W%-%y", date_breaks = '1 month') + theme(axis.text, x = element_text(angle = 45))   

final = p + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are some typos in your post and the column which has date in it is `col_A_Date` so you need to use that as an `id` variable in `melt` and drop `Col_A`. Here is a `tidyverse` approach.

```
library(tidyverse)

Table_1 %>%
  mutate(col_A_Date = as.Date(Col_A, format = "%W-%y")) %>%
  select(-Col_A) %>%
  mutate(across(c(Col_B, Col_C), as.character)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -col_A_Date) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = col_A_Date, y=value, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=name)) +
  facet_grid(name ~., scales = "free_y") + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "W%-%y", date_breaks = '1 month') + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(angle = 45))
```